# Creating triggers with IF condition

Tags: mariadb

Currently I have two tables,

**Table name :** all_users

**Columns :** ID, Name, Course Code

**Table name :** student_table

**Columns :** ID, Name

I want to create an AFTER INSERT trigger on **all_users** IF `Course Code` = 'CSC 3811' then automatically insert `all_users.ID` and `all_users.Name` to the **student_table**. I'm a MySQL novice and I'm not sure what the proper syntax is.

What I've tried :

```
CREATE TRIGGER students AFTER INSERT ON all_users
FOR EACH ROW
IF new.`Course Code` = 'CSC 3811' THEN
INSERT INTO student_table(`ID`,`Name`) VALUES (new.ID, new.Name);
```

Comment: What error message do you get or unexpected behaviour do you experience?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Answer (score 2):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER students
AFTER INSERT ON all_users 
FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO student_table (ID, Name) 
    SELECT NEW.ID, NEW.Name
    WHERE NEW.`Course Code` = 'CSC 3811';
```

PS. Do you really need in static table `student_table`? maybe a view is more reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

You have errors on your trigger, this is what you can do :

```
CREATE TRIGGER students
AFTER INSERT ON all_users FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN  
    IF new.`Course Code` = 'CSC 3811' THEN
        INSERT INTO student_table(`ID`,`Name`) values (new.ID, new.Name);
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5. Same error I've been getting

Comment: Select the query completely then execute it.

Comment: @Luqman You forget about DELIMITER...